# Sum two values ​from two on change different events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core

I would like to know how to take a sum from 2 different `.on('change')`.
For example I have this:

```
$('.AdultsField').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());       
    //document.getElementById("personasFiltroTop").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.value);
});
```

And this one:

```
$('.ChildsField').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    //document.getElementById("personasFiltroTop").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.value);
});
```

So I want to take this 2 values make an addition operation and then keep the result in other variable to bind to another Id or class, this is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.AdulstField.ChildsField', function () {
        var number = parseInt($(".AdulstField").val()) + parseInt($(".AdulstField").val());
        $('#totalNumPersonas').val(number);
    });
});
```

What I have tried here is to make at the same time listening and assign...
And here more the same:

```
$(document).on("change", ".AdulstField.ChildsField", function () {
    var sumPersonas = 0;
    $(".AdulstField.ChildsField").each(function () {
        sumPersonas += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#totalNumPersonas").val(sumPersonas);
    document.getElementById("totalNumPersonas").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.value);
});
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">Adultos</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Select(cssClass: "form-control AdultsField", defaultValue: 2, minValue: 1, maxValue: 10)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">Niños</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Select(cssClass: "form-control SelectChildren ChildsField", defaultValue: 0, minValue: 0, maxValue: 6)
    </div>
</div>
```

And render this(people not used to .net don't worry):
[image]

[image]

So how I am able to take them and put an element which says: total personas: adults+children

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Note for future reference that you should include code by copy+pasting it in to the question. Code in images is not helpful as we can't edit it easily without transcribing it manually. It's also more work for you to create the images and upload them

Comment: Yeah I didnt thought about!, last time I post like this you are right again (: .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is following the right idea, there's just two issues. Firstly when using multiple individual selectors in a single object you need to separate them with a comma. Secondly, the class on the first `select` appears to be `AmountField`, not `AdultsField` (or the typo `AdulstField`). Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', '.AmountField, .ChildsField', function() {
    var number = (parseInt($(".AmountField").val(), 10) || 0) + (parseInt($(".ChildsField").val(), 10) || 0);
    $('#totalNumPersonas').val(number);
  });
});
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', '.AmountField, .ChildsField', function() {
    var number = (parseInt($(".AmountField").val(), 10) || 0) + (parseInt($(".ChildsField").val(), 10) || 0);
    $('#totalNumPersonas').val(number);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control AmountField">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control SelectChildren ChildsField">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<input type="text" readonly="true" id="totalNumPersonas" />
```

Comment: Really thank sorry for my delay!!, I will try and let you know!, I thought where using 2 selectors must be like I wrote, thank you sir!!

Comment: Perfect!!, absoluty right it was my fault I updated the answer because I post a wrong photo, really sorry. But yeah now works perfect and I learnt something really usefull!!!, thank you @rory-mccrossan !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(body).on('change', '.AdulstField, .ChildsField', function () {
            var number = parseInt($(".AdulstField").val()) + parseInt($(".AdulstField").val());
            $('#totalNumPersonas').val(number);
        });
    });
```

Comment: `var number = parseInt($(".AdulstField").val()) + parseInt($(".AdulstField").val());`?

Comment: Thank you Zeeshan Eqbal, your solution is also good but relies in have the "$(body)" avaliable also not always should reference `jquery.iu`